# Oracle - Return records by Time of Day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large database with a column containing timestamps (date/time). Some records were inserted with the time being exactly midnight (no milliseconds). I want a query that will return all records from the table regardless of date, that have a time of midnight.

I know how to create a record with timestamp of midnight, but don't know how to specifically search for them.

`select TRUNC(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the column value with the truncated value:

```
where datetimecol = trunc(datetimecol)
```

Comment: So simple yet so brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this is just the version of Oracle that I'm using, but wouldn't you want to use `TRUNC()` on datetimecol as well? I've had mixed results not doing so.